# Why can't a particle decay into a higher mass particle?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, conservation-laws, mass-energy

I mean, why can't the initial particle (decaying particle) give some of its initial energy to the final particle such that the particle in the end will have a greater mass?

Comment: In what way? What frame are you considering the energy of the particle in? In the center of mass frame, the particle has no ‘excess’ energy.

Comment: I think the problem is the definition of "decay". You won't see something decay to more energy, like you'll never see objects falling "upwards" in vaccuum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an observer in one frame sees a particle decay, it must be the case that all observers (eventually) see that particle decay.  Conversely, if we can argue that it is impossible for a particle to decay in one particular reference frame, then it must be impossible in all reference frames.

If you think about an observer moving at the same velocity as the particle, that observer will see the particle at rest.  If the particle is at rest, it has no "extra" energy to give and cannot decay.  Since whether or not the particle decays is an observer-independent statement, it must be the case that no other observer sees the particle decay.  And since you can find an observer for which the particle is moving at any speed less than $c$, we conclude that the particle cannot decay no matter what its speed is.